# how to remove unwanted text in vi with regex or similar pattern match

Tags: shell, unix, vim, vi

I'm a vim/vi newbie and i have a huge text file with the following example string:

```
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed AS "event - tags - (all) aar conversion tag (mainsharepoint 58) - executed"
```

I need to clean it up and basically remove all instances with this sample string -  `AS "event - tags - (all) aar conversion tag (mainsharepoint 58) - executed"`

so, really anything with `AS "anything here and in between double quotes"`

Can I get some help on how to clean this up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Vi/Vim` manipulation logic directly in command line, in visual mode using the `ex` command.

```
ex -sc '%s/ AS ".*"//|x' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove occurrences of "AS" followed by text in quotes

**command**

```
:%s/ AS ".*"//
```

**before**

```
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed AS "event - tags - (all) aar conversion tag (mainsharepoint 58) - executed"
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed AS "alpha"
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed AS "event - blah blah blah" keep trailing stuff
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed AT "event - tags - (all) aar conversion tag (mainsharepoint 58) - executed"
```

**after**

```
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed keep trailing stuff
events__d5392b9f_063b_4977_d8f2_17aa2b16b070.tags_mainsharepoint_58_executed AT "event - tags - (all) aar conversion tag (mainsharepoint 58) - executed"
```

This works as long as there is only one match per line